# putlocker and sockshare not working

Tags: streaming

In ubuntu 11.10, the putlocker and sockshare websites do not work anymore. They work perfectly in windows....

Within the player there is a message that says netstream not found.netstream.play.streamnotfound

Is this has to do something with avi plugin? any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Either:

1. Open a terminal.

   If you haven't already, enable the Canonical Partner Repository:

   ```
    sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu oneiric partner"
   ```
2. Install the package *adobe-flashplugin*.

   ```
    sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
   ```

Or, in case that doesn't work:

1. Open a terminal.
2. Install the Chromium Browser.

   ```
    sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
   ```

Watch the video in Chromium.

The issue here seems to be some versions of the Flashplugin in combination with Mozilla Firefox. While I was able to solve this by installing the Flash version mentioned above, this has never been a problem with Chromium.

Tested on 64-Bit Ubuntu 11.10